# displayed in chrome but not in page source

Tags: rvest

When I click "Show Abstract" icon, I can see an abstract in Chrome. However I cannot find it in a page source.

http://epubs.siam.org/toc/smjmap/38/1

I can have multiple titles without abstract like below.

```
url <- read_html("http://epubs.siam.org/toc/smjmap/38/1")

title <- url %>%

  html_nodes(".art_title") %>%

  html_text()
```

I'd like to use this command. However it's not possible to use it because
I can't see abstracts in page source.
Hence I use:

```
html=read_html("http://epubs.siam.org/toc/smjmap/38/1")

comment_area = html_nodes(html,".toc" )

comments = html_nodes(comment_area, ".abstractSection")

html_text(comments)
```

> html_text(comments)
>    [1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

I'd like to obtain all abstracts at one time.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I think that the abstract text is only once you run the JS script by clicking on the "Show Abstract" button. Since ````rvest```` can only download the "original" state of the website, ````rvest```` cannot access the information that is retrieved through the JS.

What might work is to open the page through ````RSelenium````, to cklick all "Show Abstract" buttons automatically and then to download the text from the "new" website state.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. I'm trying to use RSelenium.